# Symfony2 - Apply a DataTransformer to a collection in forms

Tags: symfony, collections, doctrine

I need to make a Symfony2 Form and add a data transformer to a Collection. I have a StudentType Form that has a hidden field, which will contain a unique student mail. The case use is a course that has multiple Students (oneToMany relation), and I have a course form that includes a suggest input to search users by mail or name. Then, through javascript I add form collections dynamically and set the hidden value mail with the student mail selected on the suggest input. Until here everything runs correctly, but I need to apply a data transformer that transforms these hidden fields with students mails to and array of Student objects corresponding to these mails. Because in the controller ,it throws an exception because the addStudent() method of Course Entity expects an Student object.

```
class StudentType extends AbstractType
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct(Container $container)
    {
       $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder->add(
            $builder->create('mail','hidden', array(
                'required' => false,
                'label' => '',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'student_mail')
                )
        ));

    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'validation_groups' => array('backoffice_register')
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'CourseStudents';
    }
```

}

I've defined that class as a service to inject the service container:

```
backoffice.form.courseforms.student:
    class: ...\StudentType
    arguments:
        - '@service_container'
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: CourseStudents }
```

As this, in a CourseType form I've added a collection of StudentType forms and applied a DataTransformer:

```
$transformer = new StudentMailTransformer($this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager());
....
$builder->add($builder->create('students', 'suggest', array(
            'type' => 'CourseStudents',
            'attr' => array(
                'title' => 'Search students',
                'placeholder' => 'Search students by mail',
                'class' => 'student_suggest')
            ))->addModelTransformer($transformer)
        )
```

And finally, the data transformer:

```
class StudentMailTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
/**
 * @var ObjectManager
 */
private $om;

/**
 * @param ObjectManager $om
 */
public function __construct(ObjectManager $om)
{
    $this->om = $om;
}

public function transform($student)
{
    $array = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();


    if (null === $student->toArray()) {
        return $array;
    }

    return $array;
}

public function reverseTransform($students)
{
    $students = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();

    $array = $students->toArray();

    foreach ($array as $value) {

        $student = $this->om->getRepository('AcmeUserBundle:Student')->findOneBy(array('mail' => $value['mail']));

        if (null === $student) {
            throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf(
                'Student with mail "%s" does not exist!',
                $mail
            ));
        }

        $students->add($student);
    }

    return $students;
}
}
```

As this, I want to get a data transformer that converts a collection of StudentType, with a field named mail to a collection of Student objects corresponding to those mails.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you doing in your DataTransformer::transform?   if (null === $student->toArray()) { return $array; } return $array; ?? why dont you instantly return new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection(); ?

Comment: Does one email-address relate to multiple students ?

Comment: why aren't you adding the transformer in the student type?

Comment: If i understand it right ... you want to have an input/choice field ( with javaScript suggestions ) where ( filtered by course ) the students email addresses will be autocompleted. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is not a DataTransfomer but actually the [entity field type](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/entity.html#property).

You can have this type of input by embeddeing a subform with the entity field type .... filtered by the `query_builder` to match only those students in the course.

You can have it render as select or checkboxes in html with the multiple option and easily transform it into an autosuggesting input with JavaScript.

```
$builder->add('users', 'entity', array(
    'class'         => 'AcmeHelloBundle:Student',
    'multiple'      => true
    'property'      => 'email',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {

        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
            ->where('u.course = :course')
            ->setParameter('course', $course)
    },
));
```

Now use something like [jQuery Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) for the the autocomplete suggestions.

Use another queryBuilder to populate the labels to something like "Firstname Lastname (mail@host.com)".

Comment: Thank you so much, finally i've decided to implement nifr's solution. I was looking for a jQuery plugin like chosen and I found jquery-ui-multiselect. Other than that, apologies if my explanation hasn't been clear enough, but in my use case i want to add students to a course from the whole students on platform, so that query filters students by course and this is not correct for my case. Otherwise, I would like to know what's the utility of the DataTransformers. As I have understood, they are used to transform data from Model to normalized, or from normalized to form and backwards. Thanks.